# How do I switch between contexts in K9s when the contexts have already been set up?

Tags: kubernetes

I have few contexts setup in K9s. How do I switch between them?

For example, I am in the `PROD` context, and I want change the context to `NONPROD`.

How do I do this using the shortcuts?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can switch to another context by typing `:ctx <context-name>`. For example:

```
# Switch to the PROD context
:ctx PROD

# Switch to the NONPROD context
:ctx NONPROD
```

A full list of commands and keybindings are available [here](https://k9scli.io/topics/commands/).